# Best way to connect 2 PCBs side by side?

Tags: pcb, connector

I need to connect 2 PCBs side by side and I want to connect power from one to the other. It's a LED project and the current is around 6 A. Is there a connector that can handle this?

Comment: You will need to explain what is "best" for you. Is it cheapest, smallest, most robust.... There are countless options without more requirements.

Comment: Do you need to be able to disconnect the two, or can the connection be permanent? (Update your question with clarifications.)

Comment: Could you please edit your question with more details? If you are asking if connectors that can carry 6A exist, then they certainly do, and we have no details what you mean by "best" in your case. Give some numbers or specs for the situation, like a budget, as you might not want anyone to suggest something which won't fit your budget or other conditions.

Comment: Yes, there are connectors, though you will probably have to use multiple pins to carry the 6 amps.

Comment: I would just consider soldering, either to pads or a through hole via.

Comment: @SteveSh There are board-to-board connectors with 50A single-contact capacity at room temp, and if you heat-sink them via the board, they can sustain it even when it's a tad warmer. I've had 3lb copper PCBAs connected by those, and the total current going across the connector was 250A :) I'm sure 50A is not the best you can get single-contact. They tend to cost more the higher you go, of course, since eventually they have to be machined and not sheet metal.

Answer (score 3):

The LED lighting industry developed [these hermaphroditic board-to-board connectors](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=board_to_board_conn&o=blade_sckt_b2b_conn&f=hermaph_blade_sckt_b2b_conn) (my site) just for that purpose.

[image: Hermaph., self-mate, blade & sckt bd-to-bd cn.] {Digikey}

Answer (score 0):

A good solder/Flux combo will allow the solder to flow into the hole if the hole is big enough. This is what helps give it its strength. No wire is needed. You'll just need an iron tip wide enough to heat both holes at the same time.

Comment: I think you may have posted this answer in the wrong thread,